# Problem with synclient: '-m' flag missing

Tags: kubuntu, 13.10, multi-touch, synaptics

I'm trying to set up an action for three finger flick gesture using the instructions given [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117981), and it worked perfectly well before upgrading to kubuntu 13.10 from 13.04. When I follow the instructions now, the command `synclient -m 100` gives this error:

```
synclient: invalid option -- 'm'
Usage: synclient [-h] [-l] [-V] [-?] [var1=value1 [var2=value2] ...]
  -l List current user settings
  -V Print synclient version string and exit
  -? Show this help message
  var=value  Set user parameter 'var' to 'value'.
```

I had added the lines `Option "SHMConfig" "on"` and `Option "Protocol" "event"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, and did a restart after it.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, downgrading to version 1.6.2 did the trick for me. Seems like the -m option was removed in version 1.7.1. After downgrading the -m option is back, and three finger gestures work. Tell me if you need any help with downgrading.

Note: You should have a mouse, as the trackpad wont work between step 2 and 7.

Download: https://ftp7.de.netbsd.org/pub/releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.6.2-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo reboot #not sure if needed
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.6.2-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

If the result of the last step was that it told you about missing dependencies, the next command will probably fix the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Find the section enclosed by `Section "InputClass"` and `EndSection` that contains

```
'Identifier "touchpad catchall"
```

And add these 2 lines inside the section:

```
Option "SHMConfig" "on"
Option "Protocol" "event"
```

Now save the file, reboot, and you're done!