# Synclient: monitor changes to the touchpad state with 1.7.1

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I'm attempting to resolve some issues with my touchpad by getting the debugging output via [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Enabling_SHMConfig_in_order_to_get_synclient_debug_output).  One of the steps in the tutorial advises me to monitor the touchpad activity with the following command:

```
synclient -m 100
```

The problem is that the -m flag (denoting interval) was removed in the current version of synclient, as described in [this AskUbuntu post.](https://askubuntu.com/a/379791/193869)  In summary, the solution suggested to downgrade Synclient to its earlier version (1.6) which, while a decent stopgap measure, isn't really a solution for the long haul.

**My question is:** how do I achieve the same effect in the Synclient 1.7 without the -m flag?  I have to imagine that this is a rather fundamental function of the package and so it has to be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the debugging facilities have been entirely removed from the synaptics package due to changes in the Xorg architecture. There are now separate tools you can use for debugging, such as xinput and evtest. xinput only works while X is running, and evtest only works when it's not (by talking directly to the device in /dev/input/)

Find your device id using:

```
xinput list
```

Then:

```
xinput -test ID
```